# Replace date's pattern as date

Tags: c#

This is my input text:

```cs
Hello {login}, Today is: {yyyy-MM-dd}
```

I would like to replace the pattern of the date that is inside the parentheses with today's date that matches text format.

I don't want to replace `{login}`, I want only to replace those parts, that contains date format ([patterns accepted by DateTime.Now.ToString()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings))

```cs
var sample1 = "Hello {login}, today is: {yyyy-MM-dd}";
var sample1Resolved = ResolveDate(sample1);
// sample1Resolved should be: "Hello {login}, Today is: 2022-06-12"

var sample2 = "Hello {login}, today is: {yyyy.MM.dd}";
var sample2Resolved = ResolveDate(sample2);
// sample2Resolved should be: "Hello {login}, Today is: 2022.06.12"

var sample3 = "Hello {login}, today is: {yyyy,MM,dd}";
var sample3Resolved = ResolveDate(sample3);
// sample3Resolved should be: "Hello {login}, Today is: 2022,06,12"

var sample4 = "Hello {login}, current year is: {yyyy}";
var sample4Resolved = ResolveDate(sample4);
// sample4Resolved should be: "Hello {login}, current year is: 2022"
```

I created this

```cs
public static string ResolveDate(string input)
{
    return Regex.Replace(input, @"\{(.*?)\}", match =>
    {
        var parsedDate = DateTime.Now.ToString(match.Groups[1].Value);

        if (DateTime.TryParse(parsedDate, out DateTime date))
            return parsedDate;

        return match.Value;
    });
}
```

It works for `sample1, sample2, sample3`, but it doesn't work for `sample4`, because `2022` is not properly parsed using `DateTime.TryParse`. Any ideas how can I fix that?

Comment: The `DateTime.TryParse` line serves no purpose, and `parsedDate` is a misnomer. Just return `parsedDate`

Comment: I can't do that, because `{login}` is replaced by `loA.D.in`. This is why i check if `DateTime.Now.Tostring()` gives an actual date

Comment: Well, that's a problem with your regular expression. Is the format of the text something you control, or is it just any data that has a date format in curly braces?

Comment: format of the text comes from user input. If something in parentheses is a date (`DateTime.Now.ToString` parses whole string as date), then it should be replaced as date. `{d}` should be replaced, `{dd}` should be replaced, `{ddd}` should be replaced, `{dddd}` should be replaced, `{ddddd}` SHOULDN't be replaced, because there isn't such [date format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)

Comment: I'd suggest narrowing your expression to only match valid date formats. String interpolation (not useful here) allows a syntax like `$"{date:dd/MM/yyyy}"`, so perhaps you could copy that in your own design?

Comment: Well, `$"{date:dd/MM/yyyy}"` isn't allowed. Do you mean that the user should clarify that the pattern is a date, for example by writing: `"Hello {login}, today is: {date:yyyy-MM-dd}"`?

Comment: Yes. It seems odd that you have a placeholder for login, but not for the date.

Answer (score 0):

Change pattern to the appropriate one for the `string.Format` method.

```
string login = "Some Name";
var dateTime = DateTime.UtcNow;

string format = "Hello {0}, Today is: {1:yyyy-MM-dd}";

string result = string.Format(format, login, dateTime);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `(?!login)` into your regex expression so it doesn't match that `{login}` part.

About your approach, I think you could workout things differently, like using a specific keyword for user input (as you did with `login`), but here is a tip, when you have the exact format string you can use `TryParseExact` instead of `TryParse`:

```
public static string ResolveDate(string input) {
    return Regex.Replace(input, @"\{((?!login).*?)\}", match =>
    {
        var parsedDate = DateTime.Now.ToString(match.Groups[1].Value);

        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(parsedDate, match.Groups[1].Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime date))
            return parsedDate;

        return match.Value;
    });
}
```

My output:

```
Hello {login}, today is: 2022-06-12
Hello {login}, today is: 2022.06.12
Hello {login}, today is: 2022,06,12
Hello {login}, current year is: 2022
```

Answer (score 0):

My approach to this is fairly generic. Essentially I will capture any value within `{` and `}` as a key. If it is followed by a `:` and some other value, then I will interpret it as also having a format.

The expression I will be using to capture this is as follows:

```
{(?<key>[a-zA-z]+)(?:\:(?<format>.*?))?}
```

So we're saying that the key can be any character A-Z, case insensitive. It can then (optionally) be followed by any format.

To make use of this, we'll first construct a dictionary to hold our data:

```cs
var data = new Dictionary<string, object>()
{
    { "login", "mytest" },
    { "now", DateTime.UtcNow },
    { "num", 3.14f }
};
```

And a `MatchEvaluator` to make use of our values:

```cs
private static string EvaluateMatch(Match m, Dictionary<string, object> data)
{
    string key = m.Groups["key"].Value;
    string format = m.Groups["format"].Value;

    if (data.TryGetValue(key, out var val))
    {
        // If we have a format and we can format this value
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(format) && val is IFormattable formattableVal)
        {
            return formattableVal.ToString(format, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
        }

        // otherwise just return the value as-is
        return val.ToString();
    }

    // If we don't have a value, just return the placeholder
    return key;
}
```

Now we can actually put this together to test it:

```cs
var expression = @"{(?<key>[a-zA-z]+)(?:\:(?<format>.*?))?}";
var input = "test {login} on {now:dd/MMM/yyyy} or {now:MM/dd/yyyy} if you're in the US. Perhaps you want the number as {num:C} or {num:N1}";
var data = new Dictionary<string, object>()
{
    { "login", "mytest" },
    { "now", DateTime.UtcNow },
    { "num", 3.14f }
};

var evaluator = new MatchEvaluator(m => EvaluateMatch(m, data));
var result = Regex.Replace(input, expression, evaluator);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

For each match found, our `EvaluateMatch` method will run and appropriately format the text.

The example input string outputs the following:

> test mytest on 13/Jun/2022 or 06/13/2022 if you're in the US. Perhaps you want the number as $3.14 or 3.1

Note how we've successfully used `now` twice to produce two different formats.

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/XWCM55488)

Note that there's not really a "good" way to evaluate the format string's validity (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12112160/how-to-validate-format-for-string-format-method)).