# C# - Find case insensitive index in IList

Tags: c#, list

I've found answers to determining if an `IList<string>` contains an element using case insensitive contains: `ilist.Contains(element, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)`

But what I would like to do is find the element itself that corresponds within the IList to the element I'm searching for. For instance if the IList contains `{Foo, Bar}` and I search for `fOo` I'd like to be able to receive `Foo`.

I'm not worried about multiples, and the IList doesn't seem to contain any function other than `IndexOf` with doesn't help me much.

EDIT: As I'm using IList and not List, I don't have the function IndexOf, so the answer posted on here doesn't help me much :)

Thanks,
Arik

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to ignore the case sensitivity in List<string>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3107765/how-to-ignore-the-case-sensitivity-in-liststring)

Comment: If you're sure there are no duplicates, a `Where()` followed by a `Single()` gives you a one line answer: `ilist.Where(l => l.ToLower() == element.ToLower()).Single()`. Otherwise, Mong's answer below helps if there is a possibility of a duplicate. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21194750/which-is-faster-singlepredicate-or-wherepredicate-single) is some additional (probably not useful to you) info on why you should use `Where()` + `Single()` versus `Single(predicate)`.

Comment: @MarkoJuvančič I'm using IList not List, so I don't have IndexOf function. I found that question but it didn't help much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the index of the item you could use the `FindIndex` function with a custom predicate doing the case-insensitve match. Similarly, you can use `Find` to get the actual item.

I'd probably create an extension method to use as an overload.

```
public static int IndexOf(this List<string> list, string value, StringComparer comparer)
{
    return list.FindIndex(i => comparer.Equals(i, value));
}

public static int CaseInsensitiveIndexOf(this List<string> list, string value)
{
    return IndexOf(list, value, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
}

public static string CaseInsensitiveFind(this List<string> list, string value)
{
    return list.Find(i => StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase.Equals(i, value));
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for!

Comment: I'm unmarking as correct because of the need for try catch. As per this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8687113/if-condition-vs-exception-handler I would like to avoid the necessity

Comment: `FindIndex` returns a -1 value if the item doesn't exist and `Find` returns null. So I'm not sure I get why you might need try/catches... As per that linked question, indeed it seems you shouldn't want to throw any exceptions either.